# How to pass Item from initial (one time) first time view controller to main view controller and save that data using core data

Tags: ios, swift

I have been working on this issue for two days now and sadly I cannot figure out the issue to my problem. I'm trying to take one item from my initial one time view controller and send that to my main view controller where it will be saved within the main view controller and will appear upon that controller when reloading the app.

Here is my app delegate code for the "first time" view controller

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "firstTimer") {
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let mainView = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewControllerID")
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainView)
        nav.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        self.window?.rootViewController = nav
    }
    return true
}
```

containers and saveContext are default

```
import UIKit

import CoreData

class FirstTimeViewController: UIViewController {

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
 private var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
private var player = [Player]()





@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

// This View Controller will only be used once upon the first time the app is being used.

// MARK: Make func that prepares for segue on initial opening of app


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toMainViewController" {
        let mainViewController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let destination = mainViewController.topViewController as! MainViewController
        if let newPlayer = self.nameTextField.text{
            destination.name.name = newPlayer
            destination.playerData.name = newPlayer
            saveItems()
        }
    }

}

@IBAction func continueButtonPressed(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "firstTimer")
    let mainPlayer = PlayerData()
    let player1 = Player(entity: Player.entity(), insertInto: context)
    player1.name = mainPlayer.name
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMainViewController", sender: self)
    saveItems()
}


func saveItems() {
    do {
    try context.save()
        print("File Successfully saved!")
    }catch {
       print("Error saving Context \(error)")
    }
}



// MARK: Function to Save and Load data??
/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

func loadItems() {
    let request = Player.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Player>
    do {
        player = try context.fetch(request)
        print("Info loaded")
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching data from context \(error)")
    }
}
}
```

MainViewController being sent the information. I only want to send one item and save it to that main view controller.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreData

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
//set up model object, buttons, and labels
//    let player: Player!
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as!          AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
private var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
//    lazy var nameText = Player(context: context)
//    var playerInfo = [Player]()
lazy var player = [Player]()
let playerData = PlayerData()
var name = ""


@IBOutlet weak var playerName: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var currentLevel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var xpCounter: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var playerProfileImage: UIImageView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

//        loadItems()
//        name = playerData.name
    if let nameOfPlayer = name.name {
        print("This is what we see: \(nameOfPlayer)")
    playerName.text = nameOfPlayer
    }
    appDelegate.saveContext()

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
//        loadView()

}

@IBAction func menuButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

}

func loadItems() {
    let request = Player.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Player>
    do {
        player = try context.fetch(request)
        print("Info loaded")
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching data from context \(error)")
    }
}
// MARK : Add Name to Main View


// MARK : Add Xp To Main View

// MARK : Add UI Image to profile image view

// MARK:  (Optional) Create a 'Choose a task button to segue to the task tab'


// MARK: Program the Progress Bar to update on xp gained and reset on level up


// MARK: Function to Save and Load data??
}
```

If dataSource code needed I will add upon request.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you need to pass from your _One Time Initial VC_ to your _Main View Controller_?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to send to the main view controller and then store it in core data? I mean could you not store it in core data in the initial view controller itself, and then just access the same value from core data in the main view controller and do what you need to do with it?

Comment: @shubham I made the initial view controller very simple only sending a person's name to the main view controller.

Comment: @iOSer I wanted to create a one time vc  that would pass the person's name to the main view controller. I would like to do what you are suggesting. how would I go about accessing that value once saved?

Comment: As @iOSer suggested, you don't need to pass data to _another View Controller_ if the whole point of passing the data is to store it on the other end (like on your _Main View Controller_). You just save it within your **Initial View Controller**

Comment: @DreamingSavant And one more thing, if you want to just save the _name of the user_, why are you going for `Core Data`, you should go for `User Defaults` instead ! `User Defaults` is meant for this purpose only, and it requires less code compared to your `Core Data`

Comment: Have you parsed entity: `NSPersistentContainer(name: "your entity")`

Comment: I believe the following link will help you do both.  https://medium.com/xcblog/core-data-with-swift-4-for-beginners-1fc067cca707

Keep it simple!! :) Do let me know if you have issues. @ShubhamBakshi is right in a way. If its just name then core data might be an overkill.

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi the person's name is just one item of 5 to be saved.

Comment: @dengApro not yet, but I will check out the site sent by iOSer.

Comment: What I can suggest is, creating some sort of **Model** like an _enum_ or _struct_, which will provide a getter and setter . In **getter** , you can _implicitly_ call the `User Defaults` API and fetch the _string_ for _one of the five items_ and return it and in case of **setter** , you can add that value to `User Defaults`. The best part of the approach is **to avoid typos** since I believe it will be reused again and again within your app .

Comment: @DreamingSavant did you achieve, what you wanted to achieve? Do let me know if otherwise

Comment: @iOSer using the link you sent, I was able to accomplish this task! Thanks guys for your suggestions. Cant wait for refactoring lol

Comment: What you are looking for is "seeding", see eg here: https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/02/25/using-swift-to-seed-a-core-data-database/

Comment: @DreamingSavant So good to hear that! Happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

Code is wrong. You should do more check

[image]

Comment: Yes I recently changed the code in my latest attempt in passing and saving the data. I'll say that I didn't have trouble passing the data, but keeping that data on the main view was where my issue lied.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was able to achieve:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class FirstTimeViewController: UIViewController {

    private var player = [Player]()
    private var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    private let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext




    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    // This View Controller will only be used once upon the first time the app is being used.

    // MARK: Make func that prepares for segue on initial opening of app


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toMainViewController" {
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Player", in: context)

            let newPlayer = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

            if let newUser = self.nameTextField.text{
                newPlayer.setValue(newUser, forKey: "name")
                print("This is what i got: ", newPlayer)
            }
            appDelegate.saveContext()
        }

    }

    @IBAction func continueButtonPressed(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "firstTimer")

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMainViewController", sender: self)
    }
```

**And for the Main View Controller:**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreData

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    //set up model object, buttons, and labels

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    private var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    lazy var player = [Player]()


    @IBOutlet weak var playerName: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var currentLevel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var xpCounter: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var playerProfileImage: UIImageView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Player")
    //        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", "noon")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(request)
            for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
                print(data.value(forKey: "name") as! String)
                self.playerName.text = data.value(forKey: "name") as? String
            }

        } catch {
            print("Failed")
        }



    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    //        loadView()

    }

    @IBAction func menuButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    }
```